# Inserting fixed values in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Got this issue I'd like someome to help me solve. I thought solving the problem in program code would be easier but I'm beginning to re-thing that idea.

The SQL query that uses a `PIVOT` pulls data form a `SELECT` statement and one of the fields `[Cat_Entries]` is a hard coded value to be used as cell label. The values for the Cat_Entries are the calculated with `COUNT(EventGUID)` and/or `CAST(SUM(Duration) AS varchar(10)) AS TotalRepairTime` in the same sentance.

From the `SELECT` statement below you can see that a `UNION` of three queries is used to produce the ouput. If however the "sub-query" returns no value as result of the calculations. The requirement however is to display the label  `[Cat_Entries]` regardless of the value.

Here is what the data looks like now:

```
Cat     Cat Entries           6/1/2012  7/1/2012  8/1/2012  9/1/2012
------  --------------------  --------  --------  --------  --------
00000A  Critical Down Time       1       
00000A  Critical Outage          1       
00000A  Total Repair Time        65         
00000B  Critical Down Time                                     6
00000B  Total Repair Time                                      90
00000C  Critical Down Time       1          5    
00000C  Critical Outage          1          5    
00000C  Total Repair Time        30         240    
00000D  Critical Down Time                                     2     
00000E  Critical Down Time                          1    
00000G  Critical Down Time                                     1    
00000M  Critical Down Time        1                            3    
00000M  Critical Outage           1                 3    
00000M  Total Repair Time         60                180
```

... and this what the desired output should look like (** indicated empty rows inserted):

```
    Cat     Cat Entrie s          6/1/2012  7/1/2012  8/1/2012  9/1/2012
    ------  --------------------  --------  --------  --------  --------
    00000A  Critical Down Time       1       
    00000A  Critical Outage          1       
    00000A  Total Repair Time        65         
    00000B  Critical Down Time                                     6
**  00000B  Critical Outage          
    00000B  Total Repair Time                                      90
    00000C  Critical Down Time       1          5    
    00000C  Critical Outage          1          5    
    00000C  Total Repair Time        30         240 
    00000D  Critical Down Time                                     2   
**  00000D  Critical Outage          
**  00000D  Total Repair Time
```

Here is the sproc with `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT '],[' + cast([Year] as varchar(4))
FROM  vCatCountByMonthYear  where SiteGUID = @SiteGuid 
and [Year] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @StopDate ORDER BY '],[' + cast([Year] as varchar(4)) 
FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 2, '') + ']' 

SET @query = N'SELECT Cat,[Cat_Entries], ' + @cols +' FROM (SELECT Cat,[Year],
[Cat_Entries],Value,OrderBy FROM vCatCountByMonthYear 
where SiteGUID = ' + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(nvarchar(36), @SiteGuid) + CHAR(39) + ' and 
[Year] BETWEEN ' + CHAR(39) + @StartDate + CHAR(39) + ' AND ' + CHAR(39) + 
@StopDate + CHAR(39) + ' ) p PIVOT ( Sum ([Value] ) FOR [Year] IN ( '+ @cols +' ) ) 
AS pvt ORDER BY Cat,OrderBy' 

execute(@query)
```

... here is the `VIEW` that the sproc uses:

```
SELECT SiteGUID, Cat_Entries, EntriesCount AS Value, 
       CONVERT(date, CAST(Month AS varchar(2)) + '-1-' + CAST(Year AS varchar(4))) AS MonthYear, 
       Month, Year, OrderBy, Cat, EventId
FROM (SELECT SiteGUID, 'Critical Down Time' AS Cat_Entries, COUNT(EventGUID) AS EntriesCount,
             Month, Year, 1 AS OrderBy, Cat, EventId
FROM dbo.vCatCountTotalEntries
GROUP BY SiteGUID, Month, Year, Cat, EventId

UNION
      SELECT SiteGUID, 'Critical Outage' AS Cat_Entries, COUNT(EventGUID) AS EntriesCount,
             Month, Year, 2 AS OrderBy, Cat, EventId
      FROM   dbo.vCatCountEqpEntries
      GROUP BY SiteGUID, Cat, Month, Year, Cat, EventId
UNION
      SELECT SiteGUID, 'Total Repair Time' AS Cat_Entries, 
             CAST(SUM(Duration) AS varchar(10)) AS TotalRepairTime, Month, Year, 3 AS OrderBy,
             Cat, EventId
      FROM   dbo.vCatCountOnEqpRprTm
      GROUP BY SiteGUID, Cat, Month, Year, Cat, EventId) AS W
```

As always, I appreciate your time and efforts!
R.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, care to take a stab at it from a sql side? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So in order to get extra rows, your main select query has to be able to account for them, meaning that you can't filter them out.

You're currently doing [Year] between startdate and stopdate, so your initial result set is only going to have values that are between your dates. Instead of limiting it there, let your PIVOT do that limitation for you.

So the only change you should have to do is take your year filter out of your main select and you should see the results that you're looking for, I believe.

Here's an example to illustrate what I mean:

```
    CREATE TABLE #years(year_name VARCHAR(20), year_actual int)
            --Insert three years
    INSERT INTO #years
            ( year_name, year_actual )
    SELECT 'rat', -- year_name - varchar(20)
              1924  -- year_actual - int
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ox',
              1925
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tiger',
              1926

            --I only care about two of those years
    SELECT year_name, [1924], [1925]
    FROM
            --I need to select all the years so that all three rows show
    (SELECT year_name, year_actual FROM #years) yr
    PIVOT
            --Here I select the years I actually care to count
    (COUNT(year_actual) FOR year_actual IN ([1924], [1925])) pvt
```

Results:

```
     --Now I pulled all three rows, with 'dragon' having zero rows
    ox  0   1
    rat 1   0
    tiger   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks for getting involved! The years will become the column headings so I need to have those selected, don't I? (Never worked with pivot before - understand what it does but not 100% sure how)

Comment: @Risho You do still what your cols variable, yes. The part that you can remove is the `[Year] BETWEEN ' + CHAR(39) + StartDate + CHAR(39) + ' AND ' + CHAR(39) + 
StopDate + CHAR(39) + '` that's in your main query variable.